# Terraform - Upload a PowerShell script into the first container created

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need to upload a PowerShell script into a container on the first storage account created.
I have on my var.tf :

```
locals {
 sta_ctn = {
   "exploitation" = { sta = azurerm_storage_account.terra_sta[0].name, access_type = "private" }
}
```

I used a foreach if one day I need to create another container.
I have this on my storage_account.tf :

```
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "terra_sta_ctn" {
  for_each              = local.sta_ctn

  name                  = each.key
  storage_account_name  = each.value.sta
  container_access_type = each.value.access_type
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "terra_sta_ctn_ansible" {
  name                   = "ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.terra_sta[0].name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.terra_sta_ctn[0].name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "${path.root}/_scripts/ansible/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
}
```

The error is :

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on storage_account.tf line 26, in resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "terra_sta_ctn_ansible":
│   26:   storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.terra_sta_ctn[0].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_storage_container.terra_sta_ctn is object with 1 attribute "exploitation"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value. An object only supports looking up attributes by name, not by numeric index.
```

"0" on this line "26:   storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.terra_sta_ctn[0].name" is underlined.
But "exploitation" is the name of my container. It is this name that is needed.

What more do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `for_each` in `terra_sta_ctn`, you should use `for_each` in `terra_sta_ctn_ansible` as well:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "terra_sta_ctn_ansible" {
 
  for_each = azurerm_storage_container.terra_sta_ctn

  name                   = "ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.terra_sta[0].name
  storage_container_name = each.value.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "${path.root}/_scripts/ansible/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
}
```

p.s.

You haven't show what `terra_sta` is, so its impossibile to speculate if `azurerm_storage_account.terra_sta[0].name` is correct or not.